# LTI 1.3 Integration Node.js

Tags: node.js, lti, lms

I am working on LMS system and I need to integrate LTI 1.3 compliance third party course content. I am not familiar with LTI 1.3 and I need to discuss with the third party LMS developers. Can you please suggest me what should I prepare before discussing integration with the developers? Our system is developed in node.js and we don't have any LMS compliance specifications.

Comment: They shared one file with extension .imscc and no explanation on how to integrate this file to our LMS system. I was expecting LTI integration with URL, consumer key and secrete key. Can anyone help with this files ? How can i import this file in our system as LTI 1.3?

Answer (score 3):

The file they provided you with the .imscc is a '[Common Cartridge](https://www.imsglobal.org/activity/common-cartridge#public)' file.
Cartridges often can contain an LTI link, however this is only useful *after* you have already setup the LTI 1.3 integration between the tool and the platform.

One you have set up the integration, you should be able to import the imscc file into a course (or unzip it and find the lti resource link inside).

LTI 1.3 is based on the OIDC third-party initiation flow, and requires you to exchange information such as the jwks endoints and oidc initiation endpoints of both the platform and the tool. There are many good [public documents](https://www.imsglobal.org/activity/learning-tools-interoperability#LTIpublic) on the IMSGlobal site for resources.